# Perform multiple column query in php

Tags: php

I have a table with 2 entries

Blocker , Blocked

I want to perform following query

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT (blocked FROM blocks WHERE blocker = :myPlayerId) AND (blocker FROM blocks WHERE blocked=:myPlayerId)');
            $statement->bindParam(':myPlayerId', $myPlayerId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->execute();
```

I want to get values in blocked and blocker columns where my id is myPlayerId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this statement:
`SELECT blocked,blocker FROM blocks WHERE blocker=':myPlayerId' OR blocked=':myPlayerId' LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: Its OR Probably not AND also i get this {"Result":[{"blocked":"54","blocker":"53"},{"blocked":"53","blocker":"54"}]} But I want to get only 53 In Both cases. How can this be done?

Comment: I added the `LIMIT` to the query. However, this will always return the first row it finds. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: nevermind, i fixed this issue on client side thanks anywhy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want these two in the same row, try changing your query to

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT blocked FROM blocks WHERE blocker = :myPlayer)t1
  JOIN 
  (SELECT blocker FROM blocks WHERE blocked = :myPlayer)t2
```